# how do I get PHP to abort an attempt to contact a server

Tags: php, sockets

I think I must have misunderstood PHP socket timeouts. I am using `get_headers()` to check whether a server is responding promptly. I want to give the server 15s to respond, so I use `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 15)`. To test this, I can force the server to respond slowly, using `sleep()`. That is, I say

```
$headers_array = get_headers('example.com/index.php?sleep=25')
```

with example.com/index.php containing (only) the php code

```
sleep(@$_GET['sleep']);
echo 'After a delay I am now responding';
```

I am finding that PHP *always* seems to wait until the connection is closed, before continuing. When it gets to that point, if the delay was more than *default_socket_timeout* PHP reports

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

and sets `$headers_array` to `false`.  But the salient point is that it seems to wait until the connection is closed before doing that. Also, the time it waits for the connection to close seems to come out of PHP's execution time.

Naively, I would have expected PHP to wait for, at most, *default_socket_timeout* before continuing, and for that time *not* to come out of PHP's execution time budget, as set with `set_time_limit()`.  Obviously my understanding is wrong.

The context is that I have a server that, from time to time, gets overloaded and responds very slowly to HTTP requests. I want to examine its response time, from a different server. Is there a simple way to say to PHP "*contact this server, but dont wait more than 15s for a response*"

Comment: "the time it waits for the connection to close seems to come out of PHP's execution time" - well, the php scripts executes, that is what counts, whether it waits or does something does not matter.

Comment: About the script waiting for a connection close after a timeout: could it be that your server sends an early header and _then_ sleeps?

Comment: You should always check the user comments in the PHP manual for the functions you are using, those often contain valuable info and alternative approaches. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php#117189

Comment: Thanks @misorude. I missed that one. I'll try using cURL

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php 7.1 or newer, you can try creating a context with an explicit timeout, something like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=> array(
    'timeout' => 15.0,
    'ignore_errors' => true,
)));
$headers_array = get_headers('example.com/index.php?sleep=25', 0, $context);
```

This explicitly sets the timeout for your `get_headers` operation without relying on the default values.

Overall, in my experience, I found socket timeouts in PHP rather unreliable, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried that. But with PHP 5.6 that doesnt work with get_headers(). I therefore tried adding method=HEAD to the context, and using file_get_contents(), but that displays the same behaviour i was seeing before - namely that PHP still waits for the connection to close, before *then* using socket_timeout to determine how to report the connection.  weird?

Comment: @D.Gibson Read the comment by misorude on your question - and then follow the link and read the details.  This is especially pertinent if you're using old PHP (5.6). If you need to honour the socket timeout, you _must_ use curl instead.